How to Force a Session to Logon on QuickFIX/J Outside Regular Operating Hours?
I have an QuickFIX/J application configured to run from Monday to Friday at specific times using the following QFJ configuration:
Weekdays=Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday
StartTime=07:30:00 America/Sao_Paulo
EndTime=21:00:00 America/Sao_Paulo

For testing purposes, I need to execute a mock test on Saturday. Is there a method in QFJ’s SocketInitiator that allows me to force a logon message for all sessions on Saturday?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is tricky. The schedule that you configure is strictly followed. You might get the desired behaviour if you configure the session to also run on Saturdays and need to change your app to return false in ApplicationExtended.canLogon() all time on Saturday, except at the time you want to do your test. It's very cumbersome but might work. Good luck. ;)

Thanks a lot Chris!
